# Notification crushes on vibrate set

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm implementing a simple notification for my app.

The notification system works, but if I set the vibrate it crush.

```
private void sendNotification(HashMap notifica) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        long[] pattern = {0, 100, 1000, 300, 200, 100, 500, 200, 100};
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.waiter_ico)
        .setContentTitle((CharSequence) notifica.get("title"))
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText((CharSequence) notifica.get("text")))
        .setContentText((CharSequence) notifica.get("text"));

        mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);




        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

if I comment

```
//mBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);
```

it perfectly works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where are you getting the value for `pattern`? Have you defined any particular pattern or is it default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **VIBRATE** permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Of course, it won't vibrate in the emulator, only on a real device.
But it won't do no harm.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add permission

```
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

it will work fine with some versions of android but it's create problem with 4.1.

Thanks